# ViewDidAppear in Today Extension iOS

Tags: ios, viewdidload, today-extension, viewwillappear

```
class TodayViewController: UIViewController, NCWidgetProviding {

  var label = UILabel()
  var count = 0

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    debugPrint("viewWillAppear \(count)")
  }
```

In my app, it will keep on increase the count when the user press a button on the extension. Then when the user swap the notification centre away, and then reload it, the function viewWillAppear will trigger. And I found that the count is reset to 0 every time when viewWillAppear is triggered. Why?

Comment: Use AppGroups(User defaults) to persist the data.

Comment: I have used that, and what i did is that there is a timer, every 1 minute, update that AppGroup's value. However, even the debug message told me that that is updated, the extension does not know update automatically. Any method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You view controller might not be cached if the today view is closed. 
You need to save the value to disk, e.g. using `NSUserDefaults`